# Crear un instalador personalizado de ClickOnce

Tags: c#

Buenas,

Estoy con una pequeña duda que por mucho busco no encuentro la respuesta, ahora mismo estoy desarrollando una aplicación actualizable mediante ClickOnce y quiero darle un poco de forma al instalador de la aplicación y al método de actualización, ya que la aplcación tiene que dar un toque más "profesional".

Si voy por buen camino debo de utilizar la clase `InPlaceHostingManager` para crear el instalador...
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-installer-for-a-clickonce-application

Y para actualizar tendré que hacer un código para que se actualice en background o que añada un botón en la ventana principal.

El código para que se actualice tengo claro que va dentro del proyecto de la aplicación (obviamente) pero no lo tengo tan claro en el caso de la instalación. ¿Tengo que utilizar la clase `InPlaceHostingManager` dentro del proyecto de la aplicación y ClickOnce detectará que este existe mostrando el instalador personalizado? o ¿Tengo que hacer un proyecto de instalación por separado?

Mi opinión es la 2º, crear un proyecto por separado pero quisiera que alguno me iluminará ya que no encuentro mucha información respecto a este tema.

Gracias por vuestra atención,
Un saludo.

Comment: Aunque yo nunca he tratado de hacer un instalador personalizado, en la documentación que enlazas especifica claramente _Add a new class to your application and specify any name_ Es decir, que el ejemplo que se detalla es una nueva clase dentro de tu aplicación, no necesitarias un proyecto de instalación separado.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo es entonces el motivo de llamar a la url del proyecto. `MyInstaller installer = new MyInstaller();  
installer.InstallApplication(@"\\myServer\myShare\myApp.application");  
MessageBox.Show("Installer object created.");`  ¿Esa información debería estar disponible en el mismo proyecto no?

Comment: Como te digo, no lo he probado nunca. Pero entiendo que ese código deberias llamarle al inicio de la aplicación. Tambien como dices podrias crear un un nuevo proyecto en tu solución que funcionara como setup. A ver si alguien por aqui lo ha hecho alguna vez y puede ayudarte mas...

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537357/579895) puede ayudarte (si necesitas ayuda para traducirlo me lo dices). Efectivamente el articulo de MSDN no está muy bien explicado.

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh, no te preocupes con la traducción aunque me cuesta expresarme el ingles, en la lectura no tengo problemas.  Probé a buscarlo en Google y aquí, pero no directamente en SOen, normalmente me salta un resultado en G, cuando han hecho la pregunta así que no caí.